# PHP help for a beginner. Scanning file structure to return folder names in an array

Tags: php, search, directory

I am looking for some help with my code, I have looked elsewhere but am having difficulty to really understand what is going on with the code given elsewhere and  I am hoping someone can help me.

I have one gallery page that uses $_POST to change the folder the gallery gets it images form based on the link clicked.

What I want now is to code a search function that looks through them all for a string (a jpg) when it finds it, it returns its img tags and displays the image.

I am having trouble making scandir work and display currently using this code

```
<?php
$dir = "/galleries/images/adult-cakes/images/";

$scan = scandir($dir);
echo $dir;
print_r($scan);
foreach ($scan as $output) {
    echo "$output" . "<br />";
}
?>
```

that returns the echo dir but nothing else ( please note print was something I tried it was echo before and neither is working.

Then I need to get the output of all the gallery types, adult, anniversary etc and put them into a loop like so

search criteria = cake 1(.jpg)

put scandir info into $folderarray

search this folder until found -

galleries/images/$folderarray/images/

loop

if found then echo img tags with link to pic

if not display not found

Comment: drop scandir, use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: For my own learning purposes, may i ask why? what does each do?

Comment: read the manual page for each. then you will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to get all subdirectories of $Dir into array $DirArray:

```
$Dir = '/galleries/images/'; // 
foreach ( $DirArray = array_filter(glob($Dir . '*'), 'is_dir') as $DirName ) {
  $DirName = str_replace($Dir, '', $DirName);  // Optionally, remove path from name to display
  echo "Dir Name: $DirName <br />\n"; // Test
}
echo var_dump($DirArray); // Test
```

Modify accordingly

Comment: That has worked perfectly :) well after i worked out what my main issue was anyway, i didnt realise that when i put'/galleries/it went to the root of the server! once i put in the $_SERVER['docroot'] it worked just perfectly.. spent some time trying to dissect that and work out how it works and I think ive got it.  now just to work out how to use that in a search...

Answer (score 1):

This will get an array of all the files in directory $dir

```
<?php
$dir = "/galleries/images/adult-cakes/images/";
$images = glob($dir . '*');
?>
```

Comment: that will be useful :) but first i need an array of directory names :S so i need /galleries/images/(need this in an array)/